# Java mission control on OSX hangs repeatedly when I start JMX Console

Tags: java, macos, profiling, profiler

Whenever I right click and start JMX Console in JVM browser, my mission control hangs and the only way out is to force quit is. Has anyone experienced the same or a similar problem?
 - Java version: 1.8.0_45
 - Mac OSX version: 10.11.1 
 - Mission control version: 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Installation of **JConsole Plug-in 1.1** and **JOverflow Heap Analyser 1.0.1** caused it to hang. After un-installing these plugins, my mission control was responsive again.

Comment: Yes, I think we (in the JMC team) do know about this issue. I'm going to check if we have a workaround for it, if you want to use JConsole or JOverflow...

Comment: FWIW, we've opened a bug for this (JMC-4457 for our internal reference, not publicly accessible), and are looking for a workaround.

Comment: How to un-install plugins from JMC, as it is unresponsive